# how to change tab indicator dynamically?

Tags: android

I want change my tabindicator dynamically based on the tabname mentioned in the code below,
anyone who can help me?

thanks in advance.

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                String tabName = getCurrentWebView().getUrl();

            // set the tabname as tabindicator of current tab

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
TabWidget vTabs = getTabWidget();
RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) vTabs.getChildAt(tabIndex);
((TextView) rLayout.getChildAt(textIndex)).setText("Tab indicator text");
```